# Concatenate dataset in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, tar

I have a problem in concatenating compressed files and extracting them in Windows Powershell environment.

My machine is Windows 10 and I have compressed dataset dataset as follow:

- lr_v1_paa
- lr_v1_pab
- lr_v1_pac

I concatenated the above files into lr_v1.tar using Windows powershell command:

`cat lr_v1_pa* > lr_v1.tar`

and ran `tar -xf lr_v1.tar` to extract concatenated files. But, I got the following error message:

tar.exe: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format

Why tar.exe in powershell cannot recognize .tar format?

Comment: `cat lrs2_v1_parta* > lrs2_v1.tar` does _not_ work with binary files in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

As you've found, `cat lrs2_v1_parta* > lrs2_v1.tar` doesn't work well with binary files in PowerShell.

To concatenate multiple binary files into one target file, here's how I would do it:

```
# discover input files
$inputFiles = Get-Item lrs2_v1_parta*

# create new target file
$destFile = New-Item -Name lrs2_v1.tar -ItemType File

# open writable file stream to target file
$outStream = $destFile.OpenWrite()

try{
  foreach($file in $inputFiles){
    # open file stream for reading from input file
    $inStream = $file.OpenRead()
    try {
      # copy input file stream to destination file stream
      $inStream.CopyTo($outStream) |Out-Null
    }
    finally {
      # clean up input file handle
      $inStream.Dispose()
    }
  }
}
finally {
  # clean up output file stream
  $outStream.Dispose()
}
```

You should expect to find a non-corrupt `lrs2_v1.tar` in the current folder after this operation :)